# Pywinauto Windows 10 application behaviour

Tags: python, automation, pywinauto

so I am currently trying to automate a windows programm using pywinauto. Unfortunately, the programm is limited to this coorporate (meaning that I cannnot disclose its name or any code that I am writing). My problem, though, is very simple. The programm invovles a communication with a server and getting data from it. When I run the .exe normally the application behaves normally without any errors or problems. Meanwhile, when I try to use pywinauto the moment I try to get any data from the sever I have connection issues and I get no data from the server. As I have little to no information about the inner programming of the application, my question is whether there is any way for a .exe to know it is being run from pywinauto. The app itself looks old (maybe first run for WinXP and barely updated). I have yet to try change my backend when I am trying to automate and also I should try to run it on Python 32-bit insted of Python 64-bit as the app is a 32-bit app. Any info or advice would be avaliable.

Answer (score 0):

For “win32” backend 32-bit Python may really help. For “uia” backend it doesn’t matter usually. Other thing could be some lazy initialization that you can’t skip manually because manual action is slower. You can try app.wait_cpu_usage_lower() for such case. For DB-connected apps this is pretty normal situation.